# Storing set of smallint values for use in 'in' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to assign a few numbers to a variable so I can use it in an `IN` statement, like this:

```
declare @var smallint
set @var = 2,3,49,53,34
select something from somewhere WHERE number in @var
```

However this type of query results in a syntax error. I tried using a few different datatypes (varchar and such) but it didn't like that either and gave me data-type conversion errors instead.

Can I create an array or something similar? The column I want to use `IN` against is of type `smallint` and I'm using SQL 2005, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL 2008 or above:

```
declare @variables table (number smallint)

insert into @variables
values (0),
(1),
(2)

select something from somewhere where number in (select number from @variables)
```

For SQL 2005:

```
declare @variables table (number smallint) 
insert into @variables (number) 
SELECT 2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 49 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 53 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 34 

select * from @variables
```

Comment: This gives me `Incorrect syntax near ','.`, something to do with the insert statement? On a SQL2008 db I get a different error, `Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type number.` - until I change the order from `int number` to `number int`. I've edited your post. Still get an error in SQL 2005 though.

Comment: I had to use this: `declare @variables table (number smallint)
insert into @variables (number)
  SELECT 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 49
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 53
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 34
  select * from @variables`

Comment: wasn't table variables introduced in 2008?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Not sure when that came in, but it seemed to work using the query I commented above as long as I only try to insert 1 value at a time or use the union all

Comment: Works fine on mine as well... not sure why it never worked for you. The table only requires 1 column and your only inserting 1 column per value... so it should of just worked. It might be the version of sql your using, I'm using sql server 2016 (I think)

Comment: If you've got a lot of data to style so that you can insert, try Notepad++ with regex search replacement.

Comment: @Monofuse Yeah, it's SQL 2005 hence the insert limitations. They added better insert support in 2008 but unfortunately I'm stuck on 2005 for this project. Luckily i'm literally dealing with like 5-6 numbers several times over so it's easy enough to just type out.